# Ctypes struct finalization

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct, ctypes

I am trying to make a dynamic struct class. The problem with a ctypes struct is that there is a finalization process that takes place when the struct is initialized or when *fields* is set.

In the [test scripts](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/test/test_struct_fields.py) of the ctypes source I have found this:

> Structure/Union classes must get 'finalized' sooner or later, when one of these things happen:
>
> 1. *_fields_* is set.
> 2. An instance is created.
> 3. The type is used as field of another Structure/Union.
> 4. The type is subclassed
>
> When they are finalized, assigning *fields* is no longer allowed.

The structs are used for function pointers. In the subclass of Structure i have defined helper functions that fill a temporary array (not *_fields_*) with the values that should end up in the *_fields*_ variable.

This will allow users of my script to make a struct without subclassing it with something like:

```
class Sub (Structure)
    _fields_ = [
        (<func_name>, CFUNCTYPE(<res>,<*args>)),
        (...),
        ]

Sub(CFUNCTYPE(<res>, <*args>)(<func_impl>), ...)
```

But instead use:

```
class Sub(function_struct):
    pass

Sub.addFunction(...)
Sub(<func_impl>)
```

In the init function of my subclass I do set the *_fields*_ attribute, which should finalize the type. However, the fields added in the __init__ function do not appear as attributes. Giving me errors like `'Sub' object has no attribute '<func_name>'`

I suspect that the subclass is already finalized before the __init__ call, either through #2 or #4 of my list.

Is there any way to work around the finalization or delay it enough for me to dynamically set the *_fields*_ attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around my issue by making a factory class.

```
factory = structFactory()
factory.addFunction(<name>, <rtype>)

# Also redefines the __init__ function before returning the type
structType = factory.getType() 

struct = structType(<impl>)
```

The struct can also be created from a memory address with `ctypes.cast` and `structType.from_address`.